# loop jSON value in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, loops, do-while

Hey all how can i set this up for a loop?

```
 data.row9_1
```

I cant seem to do it this way:

```
 var $theRowCount;

 $theRowCount = 9;

 while($theRowCount < 30){
    $('#row' + $theRowCount + '_1').html(data.row + $theRowCount + '_1');
    $theRowCount ++;
 }
```

Any ideas would be great!

David

Comment: "set this up for a loop"? More information please.

Comment: do you perhaps need to eval(data.row + $theRowCount + '_1')?

Comment: Yes @frumbert you have the right idea there. Thats what i am trying to do but not eval.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Eval is a typo of Evil, I know. Just because google do it (http://googlecode.blogspot.com.au/2009/09/gmail-for-mobile-html5-series-reducing.html) doesn't me we should ...

Comment: @frumbert: `eval` is evil when you can avoid it (here, for instance). When you can't avoid it, and you're dealing with strings you control, and understand the costs, it's fine. I've found one use case for it in my work so far; I expect there are two or three others. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $theRowCount;  

 $theRowCount = 9;  

 while($theRowCount < 30){  
    $('#row' + $theRowCount + '_1').html(data[ 'row' + $theRowCount + '_1' ]); 
    $theRowCount ++;  
 }
```

That easy. Done.

Answer (score 1):

You do not appear to be incrementing `$theRowCount`.

Did you mean to write `$theRowCount ++` instead of `$i++`?

Comment: If that was the correct answer, can you mark it as correct, so people know the topic has been solved?  Thanks so much!